# Triggering js function with <img> onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm working on a website "kind of" like YouTube. Here, I'm having trouble with the Like/Dislike options on comments.

The way I did it is on the click of an image (thumbsUp.png and thumbsDown.png) I'm calling a js function (the following is php code where $enregistrement = the comment):

```
$block .='<img src="'.APP_IMG_PATH.'thumbsup.png" onclick="javascript:addLike('.$enregistrement["Comm_ID"].')" style="width:20px;height:20px"></img>  '.$enregistrement["Likes"].'  '
       . '<img src="'.APP_IMG_PATH.'thumbsdown.png" onclick="javascript:addDislike('.$enregistrement["Comm_ID"].')" style="width:20px;height:20px"></img>'.$enregistrement["Dislikes"].'';
```

And my js function are:

```
$block .='
<script>
function addlike(idCo){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "'.APP_SERVICE_PATH.'SetComment.php",
        data: {Like:1, commID:idCo},
        success: function(data){
        },
        error: function(exc){
              alert("Exception: Une erreur a été levé sur $_GET de addLike(). " + exc);
        }
   )};
}
                    
function addDislike(idCo){
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "'.APP_SERVICE_PATH.'SetComment.php",
       data: {Dislike:1, commID:idCo},
       success: function(data){
       },
       error: function(exc){
           alert("Exception: Une erreur a été levé sur $_GET de addDislike().");
       }
  )};
}
</script>';
```

But the onclick never triggers in the first place! I use to have `<a href="">` tags surrounding the `<img>` tags, it worked but reloaded the page on each clicks, which is what I want to avoid.

Can somebody see what I'm doing wrong?

Note: I know I should separate PHP and html, that's bad coding. Please no "comments" on this.

Comment: what is `$block .='` ? there. Are you trying to write it through php? not right. just directly add `<script>function code </script>` on the bottom of your page code and it will work

Comment: Have you checked the browsers developer console for errors? Also, check the network tab in the browsers developer tools to see if a request actually is made and what it returned. You should also enter some `console.log()`'s to see if the functions gets called in the first place.

Comment: It's hard to tell without having the actual code. On JS once there is an exception / crash the code stops excuting so that might be your issue. Try to comment the entire code and just have an alert to see if it goes inside the function. And try to post an example of your code here.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I'm already inside of a php function: I return `$block` at the end and call my function like this `echo myfunction();`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yep, I've been all morning on this, I can see that my array `$enregistrement` have the right values. But even in the browser (firefox) debug mode, I never reach my js functions

Comment: Do you actually echo your `$block` variable? Btw, img-tags are self closing. `<img ... />` and not `<img ...></img>`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes I do echo it, since I can see my `thumbsup.png` and `thumbsdown.png` once I run the code, thanx for the tip on <img/> tho :D

Comment: My issue is definitely in the `<img>` tags, because whan I replace my ajax with `alert("Hello");`, it still deosn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake: I opened Ajax like this: `$.ajax({` and closed it like this `)};` instead of `});`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things wrong with your code, first `onclick="javascript:addLike('.$enregistrement["Comm_ID"].')"` that is a self-invoking function (it is called immediately), you need to register it without the parenthesis.

Surround your images with this `<a data-id="'.$enregistrement["Comm_ID"].'"></a>` and then adjust your function like this

```
function addDislike(event) {
    // To prevent the default behavior - following the link
    event.preventDefault();

    var idCo = this.dataset.id;
    // or var idCo = $(this).data("id");

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "'.APP_SERVICE_PATH.'SetComment.php",
        data: {Dislike:1, commID:idCo},
        success: function(data){
        },
        error: function(exc){
        alert("Exception: Une erreur a été levé sur $_GET de 
        addDislike().");
   }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "You need to register it without parenthesis" ? I've tried the rest of your advices but it still doesn't work

Comment: you need to register it like this `onclick="addDislike"`

Comment: It still won't work :( I'll try some other stuff out

Comment: check your console output what errors does it show?